# express-generator sample returning Not Found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I followed [this guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable) to set up a sample express application on a shared host.

The super-simple "Hello World"-Example works just fine:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/express-hw/hello.txt', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World');
});

var server = app.listen(61245, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Then I went to set up a sample application using `express gameapi`which went through fine. (`gameapi` is the project name). Launching the application works too.

(**Edit**) On Request, [that is the app.js](http://pastie.org/9620151) that is being generated.

However, at any request, the console reports a 404 Error:

```
GET /gameapi/public/images/test.jpg 40438.042 ms - 1282
```

And the output in the browser window is as follows:

```
Not Found
404

Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (/var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/app.js:30:15)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:76:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:13)
    at /var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:237:9
    at Function.proto.process_params (/var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:12)
    at /var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:228:12
    at Function.match_layer (/var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:295:3)
    at next (/var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:10)
    at /var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:191:16
    at Function.match_layer (/var/www/virtual/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:295:3)
```

I assume this is a server setup issue since the code is supposed to work 'out-of-the-box'. But I'm pretty much lost from there on. Can anyone give me any tips on what to look into?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should post the `app.js` that you're actually using.

Comment: It seems like you aren't using the `static` middleware, which serves your public directory. Do you see it in `app.js`?

Comment: thx for your feedback. there you go http://pastie.org/9620151 its exactly what the tool generated. edited the post too.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy yes (see link in previous comment). The problem is not limited to the public directory but any request. (like example.com/bleh)

Comment: It seems like your routes aren't actually mounted starting at `/gameapi`. By default, `static` would mount to `/public`, not `/gameapi/public`. Maybe you should be defining this middleware on a router that is mounted at `/gameapi`. You're using Express 4, right?

Comment: Yes, I am using 4.9.0. I will look into your other point. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, that was in fact the problem. The script is assuming `/ngmir/html/nodejs/` to be the root path and not `/ngmir/html/nodejs/gameapi` as it should be since that is the subdirectory it is running from. Why it goes to `nodejs` and not all the way down to `html` which is the DocumentRoot I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft's Onedrive and it's not synced your project files, then it wont work as expected. In my case this is what happened.

Quick solve: Try to copy your project files to c:/user/Document(under your username)
Since this folder wont upload or sync to your Onedrive, this should work.